# How do I allow custom schemes to be executed while desisionHandler for external links was set?

Tags: swift, macos, webkit

I'm new to Swift coding. I'm trying to implement external links that should be opened in the user's default browser.

I quickly found a solution about it but this solution will also try opening the application magnet link in the external browser which is unnecessary because users need to be able to open the magnet links in my application.

Is there a way where I can also make the code allow running my specified magnet link locally?

This is what I've tried so far:

```swift
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        // Check for links.
        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            // Make sure the URL is set.
            guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
                return
            }
            // Check for the scheme component.
            let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
            if components?.scheme == "magnet-link" {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            } else if components?.scheme == "http" || components?.scheme == "https" {
                // Open the link in the external browser.
                NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
                // Cancel the decisionHandler because we managed the navigationAction.
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get rid of your custom scheme and use genuine universal links instead, things will be a lot simpler. However, if you want to keep the custom scheme, then just tell the decision handler to cancel those links and respond to them as you desire.

Comment: Yeah but how do I cancel the links? I thought `decisionHandler(.allow)` could handle `"magnet-link"`?

Comment: You cannot link to a custom scheme of your own app from within your own app. That's the same for universal links, actually. You have to spot it and navigate manually as I just said.

Comment: @RaymondHsu are you reaching you're answer?

Comment: sadly no, i'm pretty confused with all what i can search to fix the issue

Comment: @RaymondHsu you're code is ok, why are you using this line? navigationAction.targetFrame == nil

Comment: I write you're code and remove first if from you're code and everything you wants was ok for me, could you give me more detail if you have problem

Comment: I originally used the codes from [here](https://gist.github.com/kevenbauke/d449718a5f268ee843f286db88f137cc) and changed UIApplication to NSWorkspace.